# PureScript - Integer from Number using fromMaybe

Tags: purescript

Consider the following PureScript code, which is trying to convert a Number into an Integer.

```
module Main where

import Prelude (discard, Unit)
import Prelude (($))
import Data.Int ( toStringAs, fromNumber, decimal )
import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )

myNumber :: Number
myNumber = 4.762

myInteger :: Int
myInteger = fromMaybe (0 $ (fromNumber myNumber))
```

However this code produces the following error,

```
 Could not match type
       
    Int
       
  with type
  
    t0 -> t1
```

Not sure how to use fromMaybe correctly here as this use case doens't seem to be documented yet.

So the question is,
What is the correct syntax for converting a number to an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 100% clear what you're trying to do, but it kinda looks like you have an extra set of parens.

```hs
myInteger = fromMaybe (0 $ (fromNumber myNumber))
                      ^                         ^
                      |                         |
                       these two are detrimental
```

The expression inside these two parens is:

```
0 $ (...)
```

If you look at [the definition](https://github.com/purescript/purescript-prelude/blob/68f8012bc2309d9bf5832cdf7316ad052d586905/src/Data/Function.purs#L41-L42) or [the docs](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/5.0.1/docs/Data.Function#v:($)) for the `$` operator, you'll see that its left argument is supposed to be a function.

```
     right argument
       |
       v
  0 $ (...)
  ^
  |
 left argument
```

But PureScript sees a `0` (of type `Int`) instead of a function.

And so it rightly complains: *cannot match type `Int` with type (function type)*

---

What I'm *guessing* you actually meant is to (1) try to convert the `Number` to  an `Int` with `fromNumber`, and (2) if that fails, substitute zero with `fromMaybe`.

If you look at the [definition of `fromMaybe`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-maybe/5.0.0/docs/Data.Maybe#v:fromMaybe), you'll see that it has two arguments: first argument is the default value and second argument is the `Maybe` value. So all you need to do is just call `fromMaybe` with those two arguments:

```
                          second argument
                                 |
                         ------------------
                        /                  \
                        v                   v
myInteger = fromMaybe 0 (fromNumber myNumber)
                      ^
                      |
                  first argument
```

---

I really don't understand how you could possibly get the idea of writing `0 $ (...)`, so I cannot address that particular misunderstanding, sorry.

Comment: "I really don't understand how you could possibly get the idea of writing 0 $ (...), so I cannot address that particular misunderstanding, sorry."  I tried it because it looks like JavaScript LOL. In JavaScript extra parentheses generally don't change the way the code works - so I've got a lot to learn about PS. Good answer tho! Got it working thanks

Comment: This answer has prompted another question, which can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71770525/purescript-frommaybe-doesnt-not-return-the-maybe-value

Comment: In JavaScript extra parentheses can _absolutely_ change the meaning. E.g. `f(2, 3)` vs. `f(2 (, 3))` or `(f(2,) 3)`. Or `a[42]` vs. `(a[)42]`. Or `x.y` vs. `x.(y)`