# PureScript - fromMaybe does not return the Maybe value

Tags: purescript

Consider the following simple code example,

```
module Main where

import Prelude (discard, Unit, ($))
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Data.Int ( toStringAs, fromNumber, decimal )
import Data.Maybe ( fromMaybe )

myNumber :: Number
myNumber = 4.762

myInteger :: Int
myInteger = fromMaybe 0 (fromNumber myNumber)

main ∷ Effect Unit
main = do
  log ( toStringAs decimal myInteger )
```

The expected value would be

```
4
```

However, the output of this code is

```
0
```

Question:
Why does fromMaybe return 0 instead of the maybe value (4) ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's a typo in the name and i can't change the name *shrug*

Comment: A typo in the name? I assume you mean the double negative I just fixed; I don't know what problem you had with that.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not with `fromMaybe`, but with `fromNumber` (btw, pro tip: when you see a problem, never assume you know what the cause is; if you have a hypothesis for the cause, check it first, only then try to fix).

Once again, [read the docs](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-integers/5.0.0/docs/Data.Int#v:fromNumber). Quote:

> The number must already be an integer and fall within the valid range of values for the `Int` type otherwise `Nothing` is returned.

Your number is *not* an integer, so `fromNumber` returns `Nothing`, just like it promised.

---

Judging by your expected output, what you probably *actually* want is [`floor`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-integers/5.0.0/docs/Data.Int#v:floor).

Comment: I think it's a fair mistake to make to think that the value passed to fromNumber ought to be a number

Comment: Assuming your goal in answering questions is to create fertile grounds for learning for future leaners, I do not think this answer will be of as much use to future PureScript learners as your previous answers @FyodorSoikin - could you kindly provide an example of code that would successfully convert an Integer to a number / number to an integer?

Comment: Is this a good place to point out the docs would be much more useful if they contained examples...

Comment: I have rolled this discussion into an ew question @Fyodor and closed this one. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71771009/purescript-convert-a-number-to-an-integer